# I have to import an excel-file into Wolfram Mathematica and add specific rows and columns with each other

Tags: import, excel

I have an excel file some dates, countries, namely:

"Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden"

and total number of confirmed virus cases for each country on that date.

My task is to import the excel file into mathematica (already done) and find the total number of cases of all countries.

Dates in 1. column, countries in 2. column and number of cases in 5.

Comment: You posted a similar question not long ago that is no longer visible on your profile. It was closed and perhaps you deleted it. If you have already imported this file into Mathematica, then you can start by changing the title, and loading your data with the post. It is considered bad form to delete a question that has already received comments and then to ask the same question without significant changes.

Comment: How do i load data with the post? the previous post got closed because the title was apparently bad. I didn't really get what i was looking for.

Comment: No post is closed due to a bad title. Select data from the Mathematica notebook cell and press Ctrl-C. Click on the `Edit` button under your post. Paste using Ctrl-V in the right spot and format it using the `{...}` icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

allCountries = {"Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", 
   "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
   "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", 
   "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", 
   "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden"};

SeedRandom[1234];

n = 20;
```

Example of data:

```
data = Transpose[{RandomDate[DateObject[{2022}, "Year"], n], 
     RandomChoice[allCountries, n], 
     RandomInteger[{1000, 10000}, n]}]
```

[image]

Total cases by country

```
(totals = Sort[{#[[1, 2]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &]]) // Grid
```

[image]